# Asking a question you know the answer to, but not answering

Tags: discussion

There has been an [apparent case](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263397/is-there-a-transformation-or-a-proof-for-these-integrals) where the [question poster](https://mathoverflow.net/users/66131/t-amdeberhan) asked a question that had been answered in [their own paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/0808.2692) from about 10 years before the question. This would not be a problem if the question poster had [answered the question themself](https://mathoverflow.net/help/self-answer); however, they did not. The fact that the question poster had a paper with the solution before the question was [discovered recently](https://mathoverflow.net/a/263419/44191). The discoverer brought up the topic of "reputation farming"; however, I personally think the more relevant concern was brought up in [another comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/263397/is-there-a-transformation-or-a-proof-for-these-integrals?noredirect=1#comment1025937_263397): that posing a question with a known answer without posting that answer abuses the time of the answerer (and as such, might be considered rep farming because it gains reputation in a dubious manner).

Is there a policy on this, and should there be one? This seems like a circumstance that would happen very rarely - even more so because many posters don't associate their name with their MO account, and so uncovering it would be difficult.

Comment: Regardless of the general problem, I find the discussion of this particular question rather ... curious. The OP has published more than 30 articles in this 10-year period. It would not surprise me at all if he simply forgot about this one specific integral he could compute 10 years ago. I certainly have forgotten lemmas I could once prove, and once or twiced even asked other people for a proof (and I don't have 10 years of publication history).

Comment: @MaoWao I don't know why, but one of the major issues with this particular question is being completely ignored. That question is not the only one where the "question poster" asked a question for which he knew the answer. For example this question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272381/a-curious-sin-integral was a rip off from a problem from the same year's issue of American Mathematical Monthly. I can continue such examples, and in fact I did, but my post was removed by mods.

Comment: The original poster can always edit the original post with comments on where and why they encountered these integrals. The current content of that post is consistent with the suggestions in the meta-question here, so something on why these integrals are or were of interest would be welcome.

Comment: At any rate, I would not condemn people without hearing their voice. We are not a tribunal, after all. Pointing out that the proof of the identity was already contained in one of OP's papers is ok, assuming that there is a deliberate "reputation farming" seems to me unappropriate.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is an actual MO policy, but "assume good faith" or at a very minimum "do not presume bad faith" is to me a very important guiding principle (in academics and life).

Comment: @Nemo, how do you know that the user knew that problem was in the Monthly?

Comment: This is a quarrel in which I have no axe to grind either way.  But I think that it is important to point out that there were certain  preliminary goings on (which I read but unfortunately didn`t screenshot)  which were deleted (presumably by moderators) which shed a completely different light on this topic.  They (and preceding comments) are gone.  I really think that that  moderators should restore them (and yes, asaf karagila and todd trimble I am thinking of you) since they contained  relevant information.  Then the audience here can get a more balanced picture of what is going on.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not think that making a public trial here or on the Main Site could be useful or constructive at all. We are not on Twitter, please let us leave online shaming out of here. I am sure that the moderators have all the elements to judge the OP's case, and they will contact them privately if necessary.

Comment: I should emphasise that these deletions were to the MO postings that set off this discussion, not to the meta thread.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I knew he tracks problem sections of AMM. It's pretty straightforward to assume he got it there. The date of the problem is Feb, the post is from June of the same year. He says "While contending with a certain Fourier series, I stumbled on an incredibly simple evaluation (numerically) of a slightly complicated-looking sin-integral". There is no need in numerical evaluation, the integral has an anti-derivative, as I pointed out there. This throws his explanation in doubt. The evidence is circumstantial, I agree, there is no hard proof. But as the saying goes, "once a cheater, ..."

Comment: @memorial maybe it seamed like a quarrell, but there wasn't any. I let him know that I suspected him all along, and gave him ample opportunities to stop. But he kept doing it nevertheless. I flagged his posts to draw mods' attention to them. But all my flags were ignored. So I found hard proof and posted it. One of the tags in his question was "reference request". So I supplied the reference to him. And who to blame, if that reference turned out to be his own paper???

Comment: @Nemo you seem to be making a lot of assumptions about the inner workings of someone else's thought processes or ways of doing mathematics. While I have found some of TA's posting habits or questions a bit odd over the years, I think that you should not make such strong accusations based merely on extrapolation and divination.

Comment: @YemonChoi There is a difference between two cases 1) when a motivation for a question is real, follows from actual work, and 2) when the reason is fantasized, that is a person makes up a story to make it believable. I can see the difference, at least in the area of mathematics where I have some degree of expertise. If you have seen my deleted post on meta, I did not comment on combinatorics and number theory posts. Because I have very little knowledge in these areas.

Comment: I guess it is hard for MO community to accept that they have been fooled. Thus, instead of accepting this, they hide behind such words as "do not presume bad faith". I see where this is going... I'm going to be banned instead of the real culprit.

Comment: @Nemo, using words like *culprit* and *cheater* to describe another user might well get you banned. Please, stick to the facts, and leave the characterizations to each of us to consider on our own.

Comment: @Nemo There are lots of deletions and moderator actions against users who have been shown to act in bad faith; you will probably not have seen most of these as deleted posts can only be seen with 20k rep. I agree with Gerry's comment; the narrative you have constructed is not the only interpretation, and one should not always presume malice rather than clumsiness or bad etiquette

Comment: @Nemo If the moderators do determine that TA has breached the etiquette of the site, then they may take action. But flinging public accusations around is not the way to help your cause.

Comment: My understanding from the discussion is that there is some missing information to make a judgement about this case, after some deletions of comments by moderators. It seems to make this discussion a bit pointless. Maybe it would be appropriate for moderators to either (1) resume the deleted comments mentioned in memorial's comment yesterday, or (2) delete the discussion (this post and the comments in the OP's question), and add a short comment to the main post to indicate that something is going on [to explain the unexpected vote balance] and say that moderators are handling the case.

Comment: While this is indeed a curiously odd case, but AFAIK the person of interest is a well known and respected mathematician. I would be cautious to throw outrageous accusations like cheating or rep-farming. It's also heartwarming to see that the majority of the community -at least under this discussion- do not side with this behavior. God forbid if it was twitter...

Comment: @Nemo please don't take it personal. As I said, I agree that this is indeed an odd case which deserves moderators' attention. What I don't agree with is, jumping into conclusion. Believe me, there is no rush. If there is a foul-play, justice will be served in time (hopefully). And this has nothing to do with being a nobody or whatever. Actually, I am a nobody in this forum who is just an observing bystander. You definitely have more experience than me.

Comment: Late to the game but let me add my two cents: numerous times I have googled something and have my own papers served up as the top hits... it's not unlikely that one simply forgets something that was in their papers, especially if they wrote out a proof in a text or something that was only auxiliary to the paper

Comment: I really do not like the words "culprit", "accused" and so on here on MO. I  think we should try to stop using them. That said, I stand by Blackstone's ratio: "It is better that ten guilty persons escape than that one innocent suffer." So, I agree with polfosol that there is no rush and that we should wait for moderators' action.

Comment: @Nemo Saying that your behaviour is breaching the etiquette of MO is not saying you are a "scapegoat" for someone else, it is saying that your behaviour is breaching the etiquette of MO.

Comment: The accuse of rep-farming is not only based on "not assuming good faith", but imho, even illogical. From the point of view of rep, a question of the form "This is a computation I made in this paper of mine, and now I wish to find other proofs/insight/connections/generalizations (...)", would work as well, or better.

Comment: I can only explain not quoting oneself's relevant result in a question, either (A) because one has really forgotten it, or (B) because one remembers it, but does not consider it relevant for the answerers (e.g. not to influence their approach): in both cases, a sign of a modest attitude (which is a commendable quality in a researcher).

Comment: The only minor defect one is allowed to charge to this question is: it does not follow  the guideline's tips ("do a research first" in case (A) or "give as much information as you can" in case (B) ). I'm sorry that the question received 8 downvotes.

Comment: Is it possible that they just forgot?  10 years is a long time.  It seems to be the fashion at the moment to aggressively criticise people for perceived moral transgression and assume the worst.  In reality, the person may have simply forgotten that they answered the question and ended up asking it again.  Actually, I would wager that someone who has been around for a long time in mathematics or another branch of science has probably done this many times by accident.

Comment: In my opinion the silence of the moderators on the matter is striking. Several people here are saying not to make accusations in public and let the moderators deal with it discreetly. But Nemo has already written that he did contact the moderators privately first and was ignored. And after the accusation was made public the moderators have had multiple days to make any kind of response - even just "Thanks, we're looking into it and we'll take it from here". But their only visible reaction has been to delete evidence that this was part of a systematic pattern.

Comment: So I can understand why Nemo would not be satisfied to just let the moderators deal with it, and I think part of the responsibility is on them that this ended up being an ugly public affair.

Comment: @DanPetersen To be clear, there has been some moderator attention - one of the reasons I made the original post here is that Todd Trimble commented on the original post after Nemo, suggesting a meta post. However, that comment now being deleted does contribute to your wider point.

Comment: @DanPetersen I know what you mean and don't necessarily disagree, but my guess is that the moderators really are trying to resolve this delicate situation behind the scenes. E.g. presumably they've contacted TA privately, and I see that https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272381/a-curious-sin-integral has now been deleted by "community" (i.e. moderators?). It's true that a "we're on it" message would do no harm. But I can't help thinking that the mods are *volunteers* with who knows what else going on in their lives, and especially at this time of year, resolving this could take a little while.

Comment: @DanPetersen I echo Tom's comment, and would also suggest that "deleting evidence" is a potentially misleading description. Some comments "on main" by Nemo (either as comments on questions/answers or in the middle of posts) appear to have been removed, but from my memory the deletions were not of hard evidence that Nemo has provided (e.g. linking to the literature) but were deleting phrases like "this guy is a fraud" (my paraphrase)

Comment: @DanPetersen You can also see the deleted meta post by Nemo https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5115/unscrupulous-reputation-farming to decide if this was appropriate content for meta.MO. Personally I think Nemo's cause would have been better served by sending the content of that post as an email to the moderators, but I do not have particularly strong feelings in that direction. FWIW I had always ascribed some of TA's odd choice of questions to the unconscious influence of his supervisor (and Shalosh B Ekhad)

Comment: @TomLeinster You may well be right on the general point, but if the post would have been deleted by a moderator, it would say it was deleted by a moderator (including their name). Deleted by “Community” means that it was automatically deleted after accumulating enough spam and/or offensive flags cast by *ordinary users*.

Comment: @Nemo All flags are called “moderator flags”. They are raised by ordinary users, and some are handled by moderators, some are handled automatically. The formulation in Stefan Kohl’s answer is unclear.

Comment: @Nemo See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58032 for how “spam” and “rude or abusive” (formerly “offensive”, which is how the post notice still calls them) flags work.

Comment: (Sorry for the increasingly off-topic comments. I’ll stop here.) Here is an example how it looks when a post is deleted as spam or rude or abusive by a moderator, rather than by the automated process: https://mathoverflow.net/a/180693 . The post notice duly says “deleted 6 years ago by <name of the moderator>”, rather than “by Community”.

Comment: Sorry, one more comment. I don’t know how the moderators feel about it, but to me, this looks like misuse of flags. There is nothing rude or abusive (or offensive) about the two questions. I suspect that whoever flagged it misinterpreted the meaning of the flag: it is intended to be used for posts abusive *towards a person* (which is why it links to CoC), not for purported abuse of the *system* (such as what TA is being accused of in this meta thread). I believe the latter cases should be flagged for moderator attention instead (with a custom flag text).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Thanks for setting me straight. As you guessed, I was misled by the "moderator flag" terminology.

Answer (score 19):

This is just to say that the case is under investigation. As usual with cases under investigation, details need to be confidential. As to the mentioned two deleted questions -- they were deleted by moderator "rude or abusive" flags. Besides that, let me kindly ask for some patience.

*Update:* The case appears to be closed, unless additional rule violations from whichever side are committed / reported / discovered.

Comment: It might be worth recording now that the user in question appears to have been suspended: https://mathoverflow.net/users/66131/t-amdeberhan.

Comment: No, he is not suspended. Moreover, his two posts that had been deleted by community are now restored: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272381/a-curious-sin-integral https://mathoverflow.net/questions/271078/identity-with-pochhammer-and-harmonic-numbers

Comment: @Nemo: that is strange; certainly when I checked yesterday it said he was suspended (for one year, I believe).

Comment: Has there been any update, or any conclusions reached by the investigation?

Comment: Stefan Kohl, is there even any point in reporting any further violations? It seems like any violation can be dismissed by saying "Sorry, I forgot." or "I was careless. I'm sorry, this won't happen again." Your answer seems to be giving a green light for further violations of this kind.

Comment: @Negan Yes, it is always advised to report further violations if there are any. -- Every case will be carefully investigated. This however is no promise that the result of the investigation will always be what the person reporting the violation is aiming for. For example, sometimes rule violations may seem more severe on a first glance than they turn out to be in the end.

Comment: @StefanKohl Thank you for the update!

Answer (score 13):

To avoid this kind of hassle in the future, I shall do
(1) more preliminary checking about the originality of my questions
before posting on MO;
(2) avoid forgetfulness and dig up my own papers for self-referencing;
(3) self-referencing my papers in case I'm looking for a more clever
or succinct proof.

One thing is for sure: I don't want to give oxygen by responding to abusive/insulting
comments such as what happened recently ("culprit", "cheater", "troll", etc). Let's take emotions out of our mathematics that we all cherish.

Comment: please, Nemo, let's let this matter rest now, it's not worth further heat.

Comment: I second Carlo's comment: the moderators are clearly aware of the situation.  Nothing positive will be achieved by intemperate comments.